# How to format a qiskit circuit to only have a high level abstraction?

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, circuit-construction

Consider the following situation, we import a 3-bit Toffoli gate as follows:

```
from qiskit.aqua.circuits.gates.multi_control_toffoli_gate import _cccx
```

I further define a Quantum Register of size 4 and a circuit containing it:

```
qr = QuantumRegister(4, 'q')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr)
```

I form a small circuit by applying Hadamard on the last qubit followed by `_cccx`:

```
circuit.h(3)
circuit.barrier()
_cccx(circuit, q)
circuit.barrier()
circuit.draw(output="mpl")
```

The output of the following code is as follows:

[image]

As we can see that the underlying logic of `_cccx` is shown which makes the circuit too big, is there any way to display a higher-level abstraction which would consume less space and simply conceal the underlying gate logic?

**Edit:** This question is not limited to $n$-bit Toffoli gate but to any circuit which may even be defined by user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `mcx` method of the circuit instead (methods with a leading underscore are usually for internal usage and not developed for users), then you can do

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
circuit = QuantumCircuit(4)
circuit.h(3)
circuit.mcx([0, 1, 2], 3)
circuit.draw(output='mpl')
```

Which outputs

[image: c3x]

If you decompose or transpile the circuit you'll get down to the implementation of the multi-controlled X

```
from qiskit import transpile
basis_gates = ['h', 'cx', 'cu1', 'u1', 'u3']
transpiled = transpile(circuit, basis_gates=basis_gates)
transpiled.draw(output='mpl', filename='c3x_decomp.png')
```

to get 
[image]

## General logic wrapping into `Instruction`s

To wrap any circuit logic into an abstract block you can use the `Instruction` object. First you define a subcircuit and then append it onto the larger circuit as `Instruction`. Here's a short example:

```
larger = QuantumCircuit(5)
larger.h(4)

sub = QuantumCircuit(4, name='My subcircuit')
sub.ccx(0, 1, 2)
sub.h([0, 1, 2, 3])
sub.crx(0.2, 3, 0)

larger.append(sub.to_instruction(), [1, 2, 3, 4])
larger.draw(output='mpl')
```

[image]

If you decompose the `larger` circuit you'll see the components. If you don't want to wrap it into a block you can just directly append `sub` to the circuit using the `compose` method:

```
composed = larger.compose(sub, qubits=[1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer that does solve this problem of mine but are there any methods in qiskit library that does this universally? Your answer is applicable to toffoli-gates but what if I wanted to abstract any logic in general?

Comment: Ah, yes that's also possible if you wrap your logic inside an `Instruction` object. I'll update my answer to explain that (since it contains some more code).

Comment: Excellent, thanks!